# When I am running my application in CICS, I have to press AID keys twice. What may be the possible errors?

Tags: db2, cobol, cics

I am running my application in CICS region, but every time to process data I have to press AID keys (<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> etc) twice to make it work. I tried but couldn't find any error. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Insufficient information. Is it happening for this specific transaction only? Did you code this application, or are you trying to run someone else's code? Please provide some context to it - environment, code, when the problem appeared etc.

Comment: When you say "I tried but couldn't find any error" - what did you try?  CEDF? Adding DISPLAY statements?

Comment: Hi Yuri, I tried debugging using CEDF mode. I am running my own transaction. I have other applications which are running fine. I am facing this issue with this very application. Now, the problem occurred when i am pressing ENTER key to process data from database. I have to press any Attention Identifier key twice.

Comment: Is it a pseudo-conversational transaction? If so, how do you manage the flow - COMMAREA, anything else? How do you decide what step of the conversation you are in - when do you decide to send a map for instance? It's impossible to be sure or even guess, but the first thing that comes to mind from the scarce information you provided is what I said - conversation flow mismanagement. Work slowly through CEDF, and check your logic. If you need to hit an AID key again, it means your transaction decided to send a map again. Check where it decides that and why.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuri, in CEDF mode i got the mistake. There was an error with the COMMAREA value. Thanks for help.

Comment: Glad it helped. Mind accepting it if I make it into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is another terminal read ahead of your program or your program is doing a terminal read map instead of just the map in. The first AID key starts the transaction and is handled by CICS. The second is within your program.